# Passing three textbox values into a single table field in SQL

Tags: sql, asp-classic

Is it possible to pass three textbox values into a single table field?

Answer (score 1):

Just concatenate all the textbox values and pass it to the SQL table.

```
string concatenateString = Textbox1.Text + Textbox2.Text+Textbox3.Text
```

Comment: @sujatha: Nothing regarding your question, but unless you are really sure that you want to put 3 distinct values 1 column, you have probably not normalized your database :)